# MSSQL Window authentication issue with Tomcat server

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat6, jtds

I have web based application and have MSSQL server 2012 and need to access that database using window authentication and using Tomcat 6 and OS Windows

**But same functionality work fine (window authentication)  with MSSQL server 2008 not MSSQL server 2012. So may i know the reason is there some thing miss in configuration.**

i put jtds-1.2.5.jar in apache\lib directory and also put the ntlmauth.dll in C:\Windows\System32 location and also added the system variable "JAVA_OPTS" for the dll location but it does not work. It gives the error message :

```
2014-10-14 13:35:35,237 ERROR  Unable to get database connection: SQL Exception occurred              
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot open database "Test" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Then i put the dll in jre\bin directory but it does not work please let is any wrong am doing.
Also try put the dll in apache\bin loc still getting the same issue.

But as per the client requirement that want using JTDS api not the Microsoft driver so need solution in JTDS api. Although it work fine MSSQL server 2008 but does not work in MSSQL server 2012.

I follow the link http://www.dekho.com.au/dekho-connecting-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

we had similar problems with JDTS and at some point resorted to using the official JDBC driver from Microsoft. The Microsoft Driver works on Windows, Linux and MacOS and did not require me to put any DLLs or something like this anywhere.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

The only downsides to this driver are (1) it is not open source so you cannot change it in case you need to, and (2) you need to accept a license. However (2) should not be a problem since you are using MSSQL Server anyways.

Finally (I am not sure if this applies to you) the Microsoft driver cannot be used with Maven. So I (on a Mac) use the following bash script to install the driver into my local Maven repository.

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=3.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

For the JDBC Connection strings see the following webpage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

In your case since you want to do Windows authentication you need to make sure that you add

```
;integratedSecurity=true;
```

to the jdbcUrl.

Comment: But i need that solution using jtds api to access window authentication. My project using the jtds api not JDBC drivers.

Comment: jDTS is a JDBC driver. It is exactly the same driver interface as used by the Microsoft drivers.

Comment: In fact jDTS is an open source implementation that tries to compete with the official drivers.

Comment: I'm using below are the resources properties so below property compatible with JDBC <Resource name="jdbc/StorageDS" auth="CONTAINER" maxPoolSize="15" minPoolSize="10" type="com.ds.ComboPooledDataSource" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" user="" password="" jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/TEST;instance=sqlexpress;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;/"/>

Comment: Exactly this is how you configured JTDS and the very same way you configure the Microsoft driver. Only change driverClass and jdbcUrl, I added information on this in my original answer.

Comment: But as per the client requirement that doen using JTDS api not the Micrs=osoft driver so need solution in JTDS api. Although it work fine MSSQL server 2008 but does not work in MSSQL server 2012.

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL server using SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication?